# facebook and his start_time dates

Tags: facebook, time

I'm having a lot of troubles playing with the facebook API recently:

I'm fetching start_time from an event and I get this:

2012-11-14T04:00:00+0000

Which is pacific time I think since the event occurs the 13th at 7pm in France (my timezone).
How do I convert this to my timezone?

**PS:I use PHP**

EDIT: I've found a work around that doesn't work all the time, I just write

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

before using the dates functions. But it doesn't work for some modified dates. Although I really think it comes from facebook... unfixable bug?

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Answer (score 2):

```
$time = '2012-11-14T04:00:00+0000';

$dt = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone('PST'));
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('CET'));

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2012-11-14 05:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) time format.

The +0000 at the end means it is UTC time not pacific time.

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('California');
```

Try California timezone. Works pretty good for me.